# how to get value (edit text, spinner and ...) from 3 different fragments into one JSON object or data class with good memory usage in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I have 3 different layouts in Activity, with a lot of fields. right now I use Tab layout, ViewPager2, Fragments in my activity for load these 3 Fragments that contain too many fields (that in the end all of the text in these fields must aggregate into one JSON Object or data class). I disabled on touch event for Tab Layout and swipe for ViewPager and use 2 buttons in bottom layout activity (for validating current fragment's fields). these 2 buttons used for next, previous, back to home, and submit. (Actually, I have 2 buttons and handle text and functionality for these buttons with View Pager position). everything works correctly unit now except this, I need to aggregate all fields into one JSON or data class in these different Fragments as one JSON Object or data class.
my question is: 
Is there a better way to handle this scenario or this one is good?
(Considering that, in the submit button, I must get all value from fields into 3 different fragments and save into one data class then send it into another Fragment or Activity and save into SQLite database with room and my problem is here too. how I must handle it for clean code and good performance)

thanks for your help